# Passing in a template function to a template function

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

Is this snippet possible?  I can't find the correct syntax to allow for the template of the template

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void print_value()
{
    T t;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template<typename DO>
void dispatch_do()
{
    DO<int>();
    DO<float>();
}

int main()
{
    dispatch_do<print_value>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? How would you like it to function?

Comment: `print_value` isn't a type, it's a value. You can't use a type-based template argument with it.

Comment: @Mat template template parameter won't work for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print_value` is not a type, therefore you cannot pass it to a template accepting a `typename`. The easiest alternative is to pass a lambda - C++20 solution:

```
template <typename T>
void print_value()
{
    T t;
    // ...
}

template <typename F>
void dispatch_do(F&& f)
{
    f.template operator()<int>();
    f.template operator()<float>();
}

int main()
{
    dispatch_do([]<typename T>(){ print_value<T>(); });
    return 0;
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7Af88Z)

---

C++14 solution:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_wrapper { using type = T; };

template <typename F>
void dispatch_do(F&& f)
{
    f(type_wrapper<int>{});
    f(type_wrapper<float>{});
}

int main()
{
    dispatch_do([](auto x){ print_value<typename decltype(x)::type>(); });
    return 0;
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/tg3I7w)

Comment: Added a C++14 solution @NathanOliver

Comment: Wow.  Omg C++20.  The future is now!  Thanks for this.

Comment: Even for C++20, I would prefer tag dispatching.

Comment: Even for C++20, I would `template typename operator()` damnit, annoying keywords interjecting with what I want to say, nevermind.  In any case, you can tag dispatch and directly match the tag type in C++20, it would be cleaner.  `[]<class T>(tag_t<T>){ print_value<T>(); }`